# svn with preexisting directory

Tags: svn

So I have a whole pre-existing directory, let's call it `c:/src/foo`, with a bunch of files in it, some I want to put under SVN version control, some I do not.

I created an empty spot in my SVN repository for this to go, let's call it `http://myserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk`.

How can I checkout the SVN repository into c:/src/foo so I can add the files I want?

```
c:\src\foo> svn co http://myserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk .
svn: '.' already exists and is not a directory

c:\src\foo> svn co --force http://myserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk .
svn: '.' already exists and is not a directory

c:\src\foo> cd ..

c:\src> svn co --force http://myserver/svn/tools/foo/trunk foo
svn: 'foo' already exists and is not a directory
```

WTF? sure, "foo" already exists, but it is a directory.... I am very confused here. I tried with TortoiseSVN and had the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARGH -- I just realized my mistake, the directory was a junction point (hardlink in Windows)

Comment: Nice one... though I can definitely see that being confusing.